# How to pass a function to another function in Lua?

Tags: lua, neovim

I am a beginner of Lua and I want to config `init.lua` for my nvim. I am trying to pass a function(from `init.lua`) to another function as argument (to `nerdTree.lua`), and invoke it in `nerdTree.lua`

I think this should work but I got an error:

```
/.config/nvim/init.lua:26: attempt to call a boolean value
```

Why is that? What have I done wrong?

My `init.lua`

```lua
local function load_plugins()
  local use = require('packer').use
  require("packer").startup(
    {
      function()
        use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
        use "neovim/nvim-lspconfig"
                use 'glepnir/lspsaga.nvim'
        use "nvim-lua/completion-nvim"
        use "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter"
        use "joshdick/onedark.vim"
        use "itchyny/lightline.vim"
        use "ryanoasis/vim-devicons"
        require('nerdTree')(use) //Point of interest
      end,
      config = {package_root = '/tmp/nvim/site/pack'}
    }
  )
end
```

My `nerdTree.lua`

```lua
function load(use)
    use "preservim/nerdtree"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because you may only call function values or values that have a `__call` metamethod implemented.

Given your implementation

```
function load(use)
    use "preservim/nerdtree"
end
```

`require("nerdTree")` would return `nil`.

This is probably converted to a boolean by nvim as you would otherwise face an error for attempting to call a nil value. But that's just a guess because I know that some values are converted to the respective VimL types. Another possible reason is that there is already another nerdtree module and you're not loading yours but one that returns a boolean. You'll find out soon.

If you want to call what you require your module needs to return a callable value.

But as your module defines a global function you can simply do this:

```
require("nerdTree")
load(use)
```

Alternatively change your module to

```
local function load(use)
  use "preservim/nerdtree"
end
return load
```

Then `require("nerdTree")(use)` should work.

Comment: Great answer. I guess now I understand why lua developer uses `local obj = {}` and assign method to it and export it. Global function is really bad for separation

Comment: so was it converted to a boolean or did you require the wrong module?